# Memory consumption of a list and set in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, memory, data-structures, set

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> a=[i for i in range(1000)]
>>> b={i for i in range(1000)}
>>> getsizeof(a)
9024
>>> getsizeof(b)
32992
```

My question is, why does a set consume so much more memory compared to a list? Lists are ordered, sets are not. Is it an internal structure of a set that consumes memory? Or does a list contain pointers and set does not? Or maybe `sys.getsizeof` is wrong here? I've seen questions about tuples, lists and dictionaries, but I could not find any comparison between lists and sets.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it's because of the inherent difference between `list` and `set` or `dict` i.e. the way in which the elements are stored.

`List` is nothing but a collection of references to the original object. Suppose you create 1000 integers, then 1000 integer objects are created and the `list` only contains the reference to these objects.

On the other hand, `set` or `dictionary` has to compute the hash value for these 1000 integers and the memory is consumed according to the number of elements.

For ex: In both `set` and `dict`, by default, the smallest size is 8 (that is, if you are only storing 3 values, python will still allocate 8 elements). On resize, the number of buckets increases by 4x until we reach 50,000 elements, after which the size is increased by 2x. This gives the following possible sizes,

*16, 64, 256, 1024, 4096, 16384, 65536, 131072, 262144, ...*

Some examples:

```
In [26]: a=[i for i in range(60000)]
In [27]: b={i for i in range(60000)}

In [30]: b1={i for i in range(100000)}
In [31]: a1=[i for i in range(100000)]

In [32]: getsizeof(a)
Out[32]: 514568
In [33]: getsizeof(b)
Out[33]: 2097376

In [34]: getsizeof(a1)
Out[34]: 824464
In [35]: getsizeof(b1)
Out[35]: 4194528
```

Answers:
Yes, it's the internal structure in the way `set` stores the elements consumes this much memory. And, `sys.getsizeof` is correct only; There's nothing wrong with using that here.

For more detailed reference about `list`, `set` or `dict` please refer [this chapter: High Performance Python](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-python/9781449361747/ch04.html)